# cannot POST /payment (Node.js and Stripe)

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I've embedded stripes checkout in a file called payment.ejs

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_ODW7OJfVhlRJEgFY0ppWzwEE"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
</form>
```

I visit the page and enter in a credit card that gets accepted. However, I then get the error

> Cannot POST /payment

in my app.js i have

```
 app.post('payment', function(req, res){
    //stripe
        console.log('posted')

    var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;
    var charge = stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 1000, // amount in cents, again
      currency: "usd",
      card: stripeToken,
      description: "payinguser@example.com"
    }, function(err, charge) {
      if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
        console.log("CARD DECLINED");
        res.send('error')
      }
      else {
          console.log("CARD ACCEPTED");
          res.send('ok')

      }
    });
 });
```

As per the instructions. I don't see whats wrong here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routes should include the preceding `/`:

```
app.post('/payment', function (req, res) {
    //    ^

    // ...
});
```

ExpressJS' routing is based in part on matching the [`path`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.path) of the [requested `url`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url), which includes each `/` from the "root" (after the hostname and port). The other part is the [`method`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_method).

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.method); // "POST"
    console.log(req.path);   // "/payment"
                             //  ^
    next();
});
```

Note: Whether a trailing `/` or lack of is required to match depends on whether [`strict routing`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app-settings) or a `Router`'s [`strict` option](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router) is enabled.

> Enable strict routing, by default "/foo" and "/foo/" are treated the same by the router.